# mutex lock synchronization between different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable, boost-mutex

Since I have recently started coding multi threaded programs this might be a stupid question. I found out about the awesome mutex and condition variable usage. From as far as I can understand there use is:

1. Protect sections of code/shared resources from getting corrupted by multiple threads access. Hence lock that portion thus one can control which thread will be accessing.
2. If a thread is waiting for a resource/condition from another thread one can use cond.wait() instead of polling every msec

Now Consider the following class example:

```
class Queue {
private:
    std::queue<std::string> m_queue; 
    boost::mutex m_mutex; 
    boost::condition_variable m_cond; 
    bool m_exit;

public:
    Queue()
    : m_queue() 
    , m_mutex() 
    , m_cond()
    , m_exit(false) 
    {}

    void Enqueue(const std::string& Req) 
    { 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.push(Req);
        m_cond.notify_all();
    }

    std::string Dequeue() 
    { 
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        while(m_queue.empty() && !m_exit) 
        {      
            m_cond.wait(lock);     
        }

        if (m_queue.empty() && m_exit) return "";

        std::string val = m_queue.front(); 
        m_queue.pop(); 
        return val; 
    }

    void Exit()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        m_exit = true;
        m_cond.notify_all();
    }
}
```

In the above example, Exit() can be called and it will notify the threads waiting on Dequeue that it's time to exit without waiting for more data in the queue.
My question is since Dequeue has acquired the lock(m_mutex), how can Exit acquire the same lock(m_mutex)? Isn't unless the Dequeue releases the lock then only Exit can acquire it?

I have seen this pattern in Destructor implementation too, using same class member mutex, Destructor notifies all the threads(class methods) thats it time to terminate their respective loops/functions etc.

Comment: There is `m_cond.wait(lock);` which releases the lock.

Comment: You pass the lock to your wait call. It will unlock the mutex before waiting.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jarod mentions in the comments, the call

```
m_cond.wait(lock)
```

is guaranteed to atomically unlock the mutex, releasing it for the thread, and starts listening to notifications of the condition variable (see e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)).
This atomicity also ensures any code in the thread is executed after the listening is set up (so no notify calls will be missed). This assumes of course that the thread first locks the mutex, otherwise all bets are off.

Another important bit to understand is that condition variables may suffer from "[spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)", so it is important to have a second boolean condition (e.g. here, you could check the emptiness of your queue) so that you don't end up awoken with an empty queue. Something like this:

```
m_cond.wait(lock, [this]() { return !m_queue.empty() || m_exit; });
```

Comment: Thank you Jarod, super and rubenvb. Its very subtle. Good to know!

Comment: I added a small important bit (the thread needs to lock the mutex), otherwise there is not enough synchronization of course. It is all very subtle, and easy to get wrong (but also IMO easy to get right once you understand what is going on). I do suggest wrapping this (as you did) in a fixed interface so you don't need to worry about these details after your "queue" component is finished.